# Images as Planes in Eevee having weird transparency

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I have a weird problem with my viewport. As the images show, there are some very basic objects. But some textured objects are shown *through* other objects, although they should be hidden. It's obvious with the gravel – the object with grass texture should conceal a part of the object with gravel texture. On the other hand, the gravel goes some way under the plain white object, and is hidden by it, as expected.

[image][image]

I'm anything but a noob with Blender, but switched recently to 2.82. This problem happens with different objects and different materials, even with Cycles or Eevee. Could this be a graphical glitch? My PC isn't anything but bleeding edge, more kind of usable ol' buddy. Never had this behavior with 2.79b.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the material blend mode to *Opaque*.
When using *Images as planes* addon, it's set to *Alpha Blend* by default.

(*Alpha Blend* is needed for images with transparency - but in this situation only causes problems.)

[image]

[image]