# using image as plane - problem with given texture to glass

Tags: materials, emission

I have made building with "Ian Hubert's tutorial: modeling building in blender-lazy tutorial".
when I adjusted the glass material to my windows,in front view everything is OK, but when I pan in the viewport the windows are fixed and get appear in incorrect location.
how to solve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9pvH.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Related: [Weird transparency effects in viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/175755/78972)

Comment: @ Jachym Michal
.thanks alot