# Problem with rear faces showing in front when importing image as plane and extruding

Tags: modeling, materials, objects

[image][image: The arrows are pointing to the faces that are appearing in front that should be behind.]

I'm new to Blender and I'm using 2.82a. After uploading an image as plane and extruding a few faces inward, some faces that should be behind are appearing over top. Does this happen for anyone else? I've tried importing as both JPEG and PNG.

UPDATE: I've added another picture of a coke machine made with joined together "image as planes" that behaving the same way.

Comment: hello, it's hard to understand, can you please show some steps of what you've done?

Comment: After importing an image as plane (to build an environment) I used the knife tool in edit mode to add edges around the windows, extruded those faces inward to start to mimic the form of the building. The problem I’m having is not with this process (as I’ve just been following a tutorial) but with the faces shown in in the picture with the arrows pointing to them. From this perspective we should not see the near edges of the inward extrusion. We should only see the far ones. I’ll upload another picture of what I’m talking about with a pop machine I’m building the same way.

Comment: sorry, still hard to understand, maybe show what happens step by step?

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried to create a book starting from an "image as plane". I don't remember how I solved, but you can start checking normals (Alt+N)

Comment: Make sure Blend mode is set to Opaque: [Images as Planes in Eevee having weird transparency](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/175755/78972)

Comment: Thanks Jachym! That did the trick.

Comment: It does yes. I saw that Jachym had posted this above.